# How can I get capitalised cross references in LyX with refstyle

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx, capitalization

LyX (v2.03) uses `refstyle` for cross references. By default if you use the GUI to create a reference it produces source that looks like:

```
\tabref{label1}
\figref{label2}
```

which produces an output like "figure 1.1 and table 1.1".

What I want is the capitalised equivalent:

```
\Tabref{label1}
\Figref{label2}
```

Which will give "Figure 1.1 and Table 1.1".

Is there a switch or something to pass to the `refstyle` package to always do uppercase? Or do I have to manually enter the `\Tabref` each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`refstyle`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/refstyle) uses a config file `refstyle.cfg`.  You can make a copy in your local texmf tree or in your working directory. Edit the contents of you local `refstyle.cfg` file. Depending on the language you are using (default is english) change the spesific `\RS<language>` command. For example `\RSenglish`

```
%%-- ENGLISH ------------------------------------
\newcommand\RSenglish{%
    \def\RSrngtxt{\space to~}%........... Range:     figures 5 to 6
    \def\RSlsttwotxt{\space and~}%....... List two:  figures 5 and 6
    \def\RSlsttxt{, and~}%............... List more: figures 5, 6, and 7
    \def\RSparttxt{Part~}%............... Part     lowercase singular
    \def\RSpartstxt{Parts~}%.............          lowercase plural
    \def\RSParttxt{Part~}%...............          uppercase singular (sentence start)
    \def\RSPartstxt{Parts~}%.............          uppercase plural   (sentence start)
    \def\RSappendixname{appendix~}%...... Appendix lowercase singular
    \def\RSappendicesname{appendices~}%..          lowercase plural
    \def\RSAppendixname{Appendix~}%......          uppercase singular (sentence start)
    \def\RSAppendicesname{Appendices~}%..          uppercase plural   (sentence start)
    \def\RSchaptername{chapter~}%........ Chapter  lowercase singular
    \def\RSchaptersname{chapters~}%......          lowercase plural
    \def\RSChaptername{Chapter~}%........          uppercase singular (sentence start)
    \def\RSChaptersname{Chapters~}%......          uppercase plural   (sentence start)
    \def\RSsectxt{section~}%............. Section  lowercase singular
    \def\RSsecstxt{sections~}%...........          lowercase plural
    \def\RSSectxt{Section~}%.............          uppercase singular (sentence start)
    \def\RSSecstxt{Sections~}%...........          uppercase plural   (sentence start)
    \def\RSeqtxt{equation~}%............. Equation lowercase singular
    \def\RSeqstxt{equations~}%...........          lowercase plural
    \def\RSEqtxt{Equation~}%.............          uppercase singular (sentence start)
    \def\RSEqstxt{Equations~}%...........          uppercase plural   (sentence start)
    \def\RSfigtxt{figure~}%.............. Figure   lowercase singular
    \def\RSfigstxt{figures~}%............          lowercase plural
    \def\RSFigtxt{Figure~}%..............          uppercase singular (sentence start)
    \def\RSFigstxt{Figures~}%............          uppercase plural   (sentence start)
    \def\RStabtxt{table~}%............... Table    lowercase singular
    \def\RStabstxt{tables~}%.............          lowercase plural
    \def\RSTabtxt{Table~}%...............          uppercase singular (sentence start)
    \def\RSTabstxt{Tables~}%.............          uppercase plural   (sentence start)
    \def\RSfootntxt{footnote~}%.......... Footnote lowercase singular
    \def\RSfootnstxt{footnotes~}%........          lowercase plural
    \def\RSFootntxt{Footnote~}%..........          uppercase singular (sentence start)
    \def\RSFootnstxt{Footnotes~}%........          uppercase plural   (sentence start)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to the document preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\tabref}{\Tabref}
\renewcommand{\figref}{\Figref}
```

This might break `\tabref` and `\figref` if you want lowercase but it should capitalize all table and figure cross references.

Answer (score 0):

Belated supplement to @Danie Els's reply (from his own package documentation)

> When the package is loaded, it first searchers for a local user defined configuration file refstyle.**def** .

I.e. you have to rename your edited file.
(Should have posted this as a comment but still <50 rep.)