# Lyx formatting with refstyle fine tuning

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

Looking into refstyle.cfg, as suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47134/how-can-i-get-capitalised-cross-references-in-lyx-with-refstyle?rq=1) I found that it is possible to capitalize lemmas and theorems at the start of a sentence, but Lyx does not do it. How do I fix it?